# pulling data from SQL DB, Saving in browser and displaying as a value on separate page

Tags: php, html, sql

im am trying to get my head around " pulling data from SQL DB, Saving in browser and displaying as a value on separate page "

in a nutshell I am working on a project that requires you to enter customers details, the initial page (new_job.php) has a basic form which allows you to search the Clients DB for the corresponding client if no client is found it redirects you to create the client, however I would like It when a client is found, to be selected and the value to be held wether it be using Post and Get to port the data to the next page so I can automatically populate data based on the value ported over.

so far it have:

new_job.php

Head

```
if (isset($_POST['clientsubmit'])) {

            $ClientName = $_POST['ClientName'];

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'new_job_create.php?createjob=<?php echo $result->ClientName;?>'; </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid Client Name');</script>";
        }
```

Body

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="clientname">Client Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" Value="clientsubmit" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Clients" />
        <div id="clientList"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="clientsubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Job</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The key areas are I'm struggling with are storing the ClientName to the browser

I have set the next page up to:

```
    if(isset($_GET['createjob']))
    {
        $CreateClient=$_GET['createjob'];
    }
```

but for some reason I cannot figure it out.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the form variable to a PHP var called `$ClientName`, but when you echo that out to create your JS redirect, you are echoing something called `$result->ClientName`. Where has the `$result->` come from?

Also keep in mind that you need to url-encode the client name if you're going to pass it in the way that you seem to want to, if it's likely to contain anything that might confuse the parser, like a space.

Why doesn't the form directly post to `new_job_create` instead of going through `new_job`? You could do all the validation and verification in a single script instead of adding to the job by passing data multiple times. If it already exists, that code could throw it back to the form, or to some code to display the details.

Comment: hello, thank you for getting back to me, I was playing with the idea of just using one form ,but I could not work out how to populate certain dropdown boxes the correspond to each client, such as sites, jobs etc. im open to new things my plan was to elect if the client was existing or not and input the clients name on new_job, this would then pass the clients name to new_job_create which is then able to pull in and data that emails the clients name

Comment: Can you presume that all clients will have a unique name?

Comment: im happy to change that field to clientID as this is a number that is changes I can safely may work easier, providing I can then create a workaround that pulls all data from clientID

Comment: Well, it's OK to have the user enter the client name to see if it already exists, you wouldn't want to have to know every client ID. But the information you pass to whatever draws the editing form or client details of whatever needs to have a unique ID. I'd probably ask the user for the name, do a db search, if there are any entries then allow them to select one to edit (and pass the ID across to your client-edit script) or have another button to take them to the "create new" script.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a play about and see where I get on, ive just altered the form to hold all the information instead of working with two pages, I just now need to workout how to pull data relevant to the selected client and display in dropdown boxes and radio buttons etc.